# Batch of SQL statements in a single query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I'm using the following query for multiple transactions. This is the scenario.

*Generate Salary* (this is not in the scope of the query)
I have employee attendance in `Attendance` table. Then the salary is calculate from the attendance by using a stored procedure and resulting figures will be displayed in an interface allowing users to monitor / modify (entering allowances etc).

*THE QUERY*

- When the user press save, the salary figures should be inserted to
  `SalaryTrans` table.
- If salaries are regenerated and re saved the user then the existing
  figures should be updated. (After modifying attendance or salary figures such as allowances etc)
- When regenerated, in case if an employee who was in the `attendance`
  earlier but now has been deleted later from `attendance`, then the salary
  figures already in `SalaryTrans` table should also be deleted. (To
  ensure that only the employees in `attendance` table are the ones in
  `SalaryTrans` table)

The following query was used for the above purpose and I want to know whether this approach is acceptable or not, and also any feedback regarding the logic and its implementation. So could you review this code please?

**NOTE :** The `SalaryTrans` table has a `varChar` field called `reference` to hold the month and year of salary (ex value. `Jul2014`)

The `Attendance` table has `DateTime` fields called `in_time` and `out_time` to hold on and off of attendance. This `in_time` field should be used when filtering data pertaining to a month.

```
public bool InsertEarnings(List<Earning> earningsList, string reference, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
        {            
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.ConnectionString))
            {
                string insertStatement = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SalaryTrans WHERE employee_id=@employee_id and reference = @reference )" +
                                         "INSERT INTO salaryTrans " +
                                         "(employee_id, work_days, day_offs, leave_days, absent_days, extra_shifts, basic_salary, budjetory_allowance, no_pay_days, less_no_pay_amount, amount_for_epf, over_time_amount, extra_shifts_amount, incentive_allowance, special_allowance, other_allowance, epf, brought_forward_amount, reference ) " +
                                         "VALUES " +
                                         "(@employee_id, @work_days, @day_offs, @leave_days, @absent_days, @extra_shifts, @basic_salary, @budjetory_allowance, @no_pay_days, @less_no_pay_amount, @amount_for_epf, @over_time_amount, @extra_shifts_amount, @incentive_allowance, @special_allowance, @other_allowance, @epf, @brought_forward_amount, @reference ) " +
                                         "ELSE " +
                                         "UPDATE SalaryTrans " +
                                         "SET work_days=@work_days, day_offs=@day_offs, leave_days=@leave_days, absent_days=@absent_days, extra_shifts=@extra_shifts, basic_salary=@basic_salary, budjetory_allowance=@budjetory_allowance, no_pay_days=@no_pay_days, less_no_pay_amount=@less_no_pay_amount, amount_for_epf=@amount_for_epf," +
                                         "over_time_amount = @over_time_amount, extra_shifts_amount=@extra_shifts_amount, incentive_allowance=@incentive_allowance, special_allowance=@special_allowance, other_allowance=@other_allowance, epf=@epf, brought_forward_amount=@brought_forward_amount " +
                                         "WHERE employee_id=@employee_id AND reference = @reference " +
                                         "DELETE FROM SalaryTrans " +
                                         "WHERE reference = @reference AND SalaryTrans.employee_id NOT IN " +
                                         "(SELECT EID " +
                                         "FROM Attendance " +
                                         "WHERE (in_time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @fromDate, 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @toDate, 102))) ";

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, sqlConnection))
                {
                    SqlParameter paramEmployeeID = new SqlParameter("@employee_id", SqlDbType.Char);
                    SqlParameter paramWorDays = new SqlParameter("@work_days", SqlDbType.Int);
                    SqlParameter paramDayOffs = new SqlParameter("@day_offs", SqlDbType.Int);
                    SqlParameter paramLeaveDays = new SqlParameter("@leave_days", SqlDbType.Int);
                    SqlParameter paramAbsentDays = new SqlParameter("@absent_days", SqlDbType.Int);
                    SqlParameter paramExtraShifts = new SqlParameter("@extra_shifts", SqlDbType.Int);
                    SqlParameter paramBasicSalary = new SqlParameter("@basic_salary", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramBudjAllowance = new SqlParameter("@budjetory_allowance", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramNoPayDays = new SqlParameter("@no_pay_days", SqlDbType.Int);
                    SqlParameter paramLessNoPay = new SqlParameter("@less_no_pay_amount", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramAmountForEPF = new SqlParameter("@amount_for_epf", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramOverTime = new SqlParameter("@over_time_amount", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramExtraShiftsAmount = new SqlParameter("@extra_shifts_amount", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramIncentiveAllowance = new SqlParameter("@incentive_allowance", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramSpecialAllowance = new SqlParameter("@special_allowance", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramOtherAllowance = new SqlParameter("@other_allowance", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramBFAmount = new SqlParameter("@brought_forward_amount", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramEpf = new SqlParameter("@epf", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    SqlParameter paramReference = new SqlParameter("@reference", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter paramFromDate = new SqlParameter("@fromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                    SqlParameter paramToDate = new SqlParameter("@toDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);

                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramEmployeeID);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramWorDays);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramDayOffs);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramLeaveDays);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramAbsentDays);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramExtraShifts);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramBasicSalary);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramBudjAllowance);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramNoPayDays);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramLessNoPay);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramAmountForEPF);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramOverTime);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramExtraShiftsAmount);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramIncentiveAllowance);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramSpecialAllowance);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramOtherAllowance);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramBFAmount);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramEpf);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramReference);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramFromDate);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramToDate);

                        sqlConnection.Open();
                        SqlTransaction sqlTrans = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("Insert");
                        sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans;
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (Earning earning in earningsList)
                            {
                                paramEmployeeID.Value = earning.EmployeeID;
                                paramWorDays.Value = earning.WorkDays;
                                paramDayOffs.Value = earning.DayOffs;
                                paramLeaveDays.Value = earning.LeaveDays;
                                paramAbsentDays.Value = earning.AbsentDays;
                                paramExtraShifts.Value = earning.ExtraShifts;
                                paramBasicSalary.Value = earning.BasicSalaryAmount;
                                paramBudjAllowance.Value = earning.BudjetoryAllowance;
                                paramNoPayDays.Value = earning.NoPayDays;
                                paramLessNoPay.Value = earning.LessNoPayAmount;
                                paramAmountForEPF.Value = earning.AmountForEPF;
                                paramOverTime.Value = earning.OverTimeAmount;
                                paramExtraShiftsAmount.Value = earning.ExtraShiftAmount;
                                paramIncentiveAllowance.Value = earning.IncentiveAllowance;
                                paramSpecialAllowance.Value = earning.SpecialAllowance;
                                paramOtherAllowance.Value = earning.OtherAllowance;
                                paramBFAmount.Value = earning.BroughtForwardAmount;
                                paramEpf.Value = earning.AmountForEPF / 100 * 8;
                                paramReference.Value = reference;
                                paramToDate.Value = toDate;
                                paramFromDate.Value = fromDate;

                                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            sqlTrans.Commit();
                            return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(("Error: " + e.Message)); }
                    sqlTrans.Rollback();
                    if (sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) sqlConnection.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be working as it is.

Comment: @ Phrancis, @200_success♦, Well, I had posted only the query part of the code as the code is very lengthy. But is a working code. Anyway I edited the question and now full code is available. Hope you would reopen the post.

Comment: That's actually a much more interesting question to review, with the real code.

Comment: are employee salary generation is related to each other? if not why transaction has been opened before loop, your transnational code should be small,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this method is quite large, let's start digging through the code.

- `insertStatement` should be a `const` on class level
- The creation of the SqlParameters can be extracted to a method

  ```
  private SqlParameter[] GetInsertEarningsParameters()
  {
      //I use a List<T> because it is easier to read.
      List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@employee_id", SqlDbType.Char));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@work_days", SqlDbType.Int));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day_offs", SqlDbType.Int));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@leave_days", SqlDbType.Int));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@absent_days", SqlDbType.Int));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@extra_shifts", SqlDbType.Int));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@basic_salary", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@budjetory_allowance", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@no_pay_days", SqlDbType.Int));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@less_no_pay_amount", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@amount_for_epf", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@over_time_amount", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@extra_shifts_amount", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@incentive_allowance", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@special_allowance", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@other_allowance", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@brought_forward_amount", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@epf", SqlDbType.Decimal));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@reference", SqlDbType.VarChar));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
      sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@toDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));

      return sqlParameters.ToArray();
  }
  ```

  and then be called

  ```
  sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(GetInsertEarningsParameters());
  ```
- As the values for `reference`, `toDate` and `fromDate` won't change, we will assign the parameter values before the `foreach` loop only once

  ```
  sqlCommand.Parameters["@reference"].Value = reference;
  sqlCommand.Parameters["@toDate"].Value = toDate;
  sqlCommand.Parameters["@fromDate"].Value = fromDate;
  ```
- The assignments of the values of the `Earning`'s object should be extracted to a method and the `magic number` **100 * 8** should be a const

  ```
  private const int AMOUNT_FOR_EPF_DIVISOR = 100 * 8;
  private void FillInsertEarningsParameterValues(Earning earning, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
  {
      parameters["@employee_id"].Value = earning.EmployeeID;
      parameters["@work_days"].Value = earning.WorkDays;
      parameters["@day_offs"].Value = earning.DayOffs;
      parameters["@leave_days"].Value = earning.LeaveDays;
      parameters["@absent_days"].Value = earning.AbsentDays;
      parameters["@extra_shifts"].Value = earning.ExtraShifts;
      parameters["@basic_salary"].Value = earning.BasicSalaryAmount;
      parameters["@budjetory_allowance"].Value = earning.BudjetoryAllowance;
      parameters["@no_pay_days"].Value = earning.NoPayDays;
      parameters["@less_no_pay_amount"].Value = earning.LessNoPayAmount;
      parameters["@amount_for_epf"].Value = earning.AmountForEPF;
      parameters["@over_time_amount"].Value = earning.OverTimeAmount;
      parameters["@extra_shifts_amount"].Value = earning.ExtraShiftAmount;
      parameters["@incentive_allowance"].Value = earning.IncentiveAllowance;
      parameters["@special_allowance"].Value = earning.SpecialAllowance;
      parameters["@other_allowance"].Value = earning.OtherAllowance;
      parameters["@brought_forward_amount"].Value = earning.BroughtForwardAmount;
      parameters["@epf"].Value = earning.AmountForEPF / AMOUNT_FOR_EPF_DIVISOR;
  }
  ```

  now the `foreach` will be

  ```
  foreach (Earning earning in earningsList)
  {
      FillInsertEarningsParameterValues(earning,sqlCommand.Parameters);

      sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  ```
- The result of the refactoring of your large method would be

  ```
  public bool InsertEarnings(List<Earning> earningsList, string reference, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
  {
      using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.ConnectionString))
      {

          using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, sqlConnection))
          {
              sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(GetInsertEarningsParameters());

              sqlCommand.Parameters["@reference"].Value = reference;
              sqlCommand.Parameters["@toDate"].Value = toDate;
              sqlCommand.Parameters["@fromDate"].Value = fromDate;

              sqlConnection.Open();
              SqlTransaction sqlTrans = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("Insert");
              sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans;
              try
              {
                  foreach (Earning earning in earningsList)
                  {
                      FillInsertEarningsParameterValues(earning, sqlCommand.Parameters);

                      sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  }
                  sqlTrans.Commit();
                  return true;
              }
              catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(("Error: " + e.Message)); }
              sqlTrans.Rollback();
              if (sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) sqlConnection.Close();
              return false;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Nice review thanks. What about the SQL part?

Comment: @Chathuranga What do you mean with SQL part ?

Comment: I meant the query. If you would say its ok, it suffice

Comment: @Chathuranga I am not the expert with sql statements. You can extract the sql statement and create a new question with the `sql` tag